# csrf token for ajax in django2

Tags: ajax, django, django-csrf

I am learning Django2,and try to make a login page with csrf_token and ajax.

I hope that if user hasn't lgoin,that will turn to the login page and send a variable `next` as a tag of the page before login.If user login successfully that I can turn to the homepage or page marked by `next`.

I read the docs of Django2, and try to code like below,however,when I click "LOGIN" button,it just refresh the login page and get no error

I am confused and have no idea already.Please help.

login views:

```
def login(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        uf = UserForm(request.POST)
        if uf.is_valid():
            # get info from form
            username = uf.cleaned_data['username']
            password = uf.cleaned_data['password']
            user = auth.authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:  # user match
                auth.login(request, user)
                if request.GET.get('next'):
                    next_url = request.GET.get('next')
                    return JsonResponse({'redirect_url': next_url})
                    # return redirect(request.GET.get('next'))
                else:
                    return JsonResponse({'redirect_url': 'home'})
            else:  # user not match
                error_msg = ["username or pwd mistake"]
                return JsonResponse({'error_msg': error_msg})
    else:
        uf = UserForm()
    return render(request, 'login.html', {'uf': uf})
```

html :

```
    <form>
      {% csrf_token %}
       {{ uf.username }}
       {{ uf.password }}
      <div id="errorMsg"></div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="loginButton">login</button>
     <input type="hidden" name="next" id="redirect-next" value="{{ next|escape }}"/>
   </form>
```

JQuery:

```
       $("#loginButton").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "json",
        data: {username: $("#inputEmail3").val(), password: $("#inputPassword3").val()},
        beforeSend: function (xhr, settings) {
            var csrftoken = Cookies.get('csrftoken');
            function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
                // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
                return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
            }
            if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
            }
        },
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.error_msg) {
                $('#errorMsg').show().text('user info error') //print an alert on the page
            }
            else {
                location.href = result.redirect_url //turn to homepage or page before login
            }
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Change your type from `submit` to `button`. `submit` type will lead to your form being submitted instead of on click event being triggered. Also check out my answer on a better way to implement the login system in django.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to take effort to write a login view of your own like this. Django provides easier methods to implement it.

First make sure the following are included in your `settings.py`

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    ...
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    ...
]
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    ...
]
```

Add all the login URLs to your main `urls.py`:

```
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import include


urlpatterns = [
....
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
....
]
```

Don't forget to run `python manage.py migrate` to create the tables required for the `auth` app. Now that the app and URLs are ready, templates need to be created. All the templates for the app should be placed under a folder named `registration` under your `templates` directory. The directory structure should be something like.

```
your_django_app/
    templates/
        registration/
            login.html
    __init__.py
    apps.py
    settings.py
    urls.py
    views.py
    wsgi.py
```

The contents of the `login.html` should be something like:

```
<form id="loginform" action="{% url 'login' %}" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
{% if next %}
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
{% endif %}
    <input name="username" id="id_username" type="text">
    <label>Username</label>
    <input name="password" id="id_password" type="password">
    <label>Password</label>
{% if form.errors %}
    Error! Wrong credentials.
{% endif %}
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

After this include these in your `settings.py` file for redirecting users correctly after login.

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
LOGIN_URL = '/accounts/login'
```

You are all set to go. Make sure to create at least one user before trying this out by running `python manage.py createsuperuser`. For all pages that require users to login before viewing them you can use the `@login_required` decorator above their respective view functions to redirect them to the login page before showing the page. Example:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home/index.html')
```

Comment: Actually I  have used 'auth'  and added @login_required in each page^^ I change the type of button and use HttpResponse(json.dumps.....) instead of JsonResponse(....),it works.It's so kind of you^^thanks

Comment: I just mentioned a cleaner method. I thought ajax and jquery were a bit too much for a simple login page.

Comment: ajax just for showing some error messages like "username or password error" without refresh the login page.

Answer (score 2):

**Here there is a short and simple way to parse the csrf_token using ajax:**

*Inside the script tag.*

```
    $.ajax({
           url: window.location.pathname,
           type: 'POST',
           data: {
                 ......,
                // Note this step.
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken': "{{ csrf_token }}"
                },
                success: function() {
                   .....
                }
    });
```

*Hope things work well as I have used this thing to parse the csrf_token in my 2 Django based projects. Cheers!*

Comment: The only problem with this is that follow up ajax requests don't work.

Answer (score 1):

This might be related to this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932653/how-to-prevent-buttons-from-submitting-forms)

As your button tries to submit the form but you want it to be handled handled by the script.

try changing the button type to

```
type="button"
```